# Conditional form field checks

Tags: php

I have the following to check weather a form field is populated or not. If the $priceperperson field is set then calculate the $rentalprice based on that, if its not, then calculate the $rental price based on the $baserentalprice.

```
$priceperperson = ($_POST['priceperperson']);
$baserentalprice = ($_POST['rentalprice']);
$numberofguests = ($_POST['numberofguests']);
 if (isset($priceperperson)) {
  $rentalprice = ($priceperperson * $numberofguests * $numberofnights);
 } elseif (!isset($priceperperson)) {
  $rentalprice = $baserentalprice;
 }
```

UPDATE:
My problem is that I dont seem to be able to set the rental price as $baserentalprice. The $priceperperson calculation works but when i delete the content of the $priceperperson field from the form and fire the ajax again, it wont work. Either way, its failing after the 'else'.

Comment: use $priceperperson = $_POST['priceperperson']; remove bracket from post

Comment: Im using this format throughout the site and haven't had a problem with it so far. But thanks.

Comment: it will never go to else if as you are setting the varibale.. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change block

```
if (isset($priceperperson)) {
  $rentalprice = ($priceperperson * $numberofguests * $numberofnights);
 } elseif (!isset($priceperperson)) {
  $rentalprice = $baserentalprice;
 }
```

to

```
if (isset($priceperperson) && $priceperperson != '') {
  $rentalprice = ($priceperperson * $numberofguests * $numberofnights);
 } else {
  $rentalprice = $baserentalprice;
 }
```

Comment: Then how do i set the value of $priceperperson for the calculation on line 5?

Comment: just keep the line $priceperperson = ($_POST['priceperperson']); and while checking just check if(isset($_POST['priceperperson']))

best is to add the line $priceperperson = ($_POST['priceperperson']);

inside  like if(isset($_POST['priceperperson'])){  $priceperperson = ($_POST['priceperperson']);}

Comment: Still not liking it. Is there another way I can check to see if that $priceperperson field has data in it. Perhaps inside the javascript for the ajax request?

Comment: your problem is your execution never goes inside the else if block..?

Comment: change block 

if (isset($priceperperson)) {
  $rentalprice = ($priceperperson * $numberofguests * $numberofnights);
 } elseif (!isset($priceperperson)) {
  $rentalprice = $baserentalprice;
 }

to

if (isset($priceperperson) && $priceperperson != '') {
  $rentalprice = ($priceperperson * $numberofguests * $numberofnights);
 } else {
  $rentalprice = $baserentalprice;
 }

Comment: Correct. Every time i fire the ajax request with the $priceperperson input empty, i get back a 0 in the input.

Comment: Yes I see what you have done. You have simplified my block by removing the need for a second if. That works great. Thanks very much. If you add that answer as a seperate comment Ill mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

[`isset()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will return `true` if the variable is set but empty (eg. `''`). You can use [`empty()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead.

```
if (!empty($priceperperson)) { /* ... */ }
```

Be careful, though. If you are expecting eg. `0` then `empty` will return `true` which may not be desired.

Generally, it is recommended to do `isset` or `empty` checks first, though. This will prevent warnings from being generated.

You can easily do so with the [ternary operator](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
$priceperperson = isset($_POST['priceperperson']) ? $_POST['priceperperson'] : '';
$baserentalprice = isset($_POST['rentalprice']) ? $_POST['rentalprice'] : '';
$numberofguests = isset($_POST['numberofguests']) ? $_POST['numberofguests'] : '';

if ($priceperperson) {
    $rentalprice = ($priceperperson * $numberofguests * $numberofnights);
} else {
    $rentalprice = $baserentalprice;
}
```

You no longer need the `isset` (or `empty`) in your `if` since you already checked that. You can change the condition to `$priceperperson != ''` if you want to allow eg. `0` as a valid value.

I also changed your `elseif` for a regular `else` since the condition was simply inverted.